# duplicating data when fetch from database in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

My code returns duplicate data. Please help me.

I have 3 tables:

**Accommodation  Table**

```
------------ --------------
fldProductID fldProductID
------------ --------------
1              6
2              6
```

**AccommodationText Table**

```
---------------------- ------------- -------------------
fldAccommodationTextID fldProductID fldAccommodationText
---------------------- ------------- -------------------
1                       6             text 1
2                       6             text 2
3                       10            text 4
4                       11            text 8
```

**Product table**

```
------------ --------
fldProductID seo_url
------------ --------
6           next_1
7           next_2
```

This is my query

```php
$this->db->select('seo_url, Accommodation.fldProductID, fldAccommodationTextID');
$this->db->where('fldAccommodationDelete', '0');  
$this->db->where('seo_url', '6');
$this->db->from('Accommodation');
$this->db->join('Product', 'Product.fldProductID =  Accommodation.fldProductID', 'left');
$this->db->join('AccommodationText', 'AccommodationText.fldProductID = Accommodation.fldProductID');
$query = $this->db->get(); 
echo '<pre>'; 
var_dump($query->result()); 
echo'</pre>'; 
die;
```

Comment: It is not clear what your question or problem is.

Comment: Show expected and actual result (update question, not in comments)

Comment: I'm expected only 2 out put in row . but that value duplicate in same value. that code actually display 4 values . please help me <pre>next_1 6 text 1 next_1 6 text 2 next_1 6 text 1 next_1 6 text 2</pre>

Comment: Can you add the expected output.